# Advanced MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  Employees
  EmpID : int(10)
  Firstname: varchar(100)
  Lastname: varchar(100)
  HireDate: timestamp
  TerminationDate: timestamp

  AnnualReviews
  EmpID: int(10)
  ReviewDate: timestamp
```

What is query to calculate the longest period (in days) that the company has gone without a hiring or firing anyone.?

So far, this is my query :

```
SELECT max(abs(datediff((select max(terminationdate) 
                         from employees 
                         where terminationdate < t.terminationdate),
               terminationdate))),
max(abs(datediff((select max(hiredate) 
                  from employees 
                  where hiredate <  t.hiredate), 
         hiredate)))
FROM employees AS t
```

I do not know how to compare date for each row at same field..

Comment: I smell.. homework. What have you done so far?

Comment: SELECT max(abs(datediff((select max(terminationdate) from employees where terminationdate < t.terminationdate), terminationdate))),max(abs(datediff((select max(hiredate) from employees where hiredate < t.hiredate), hiredate)))
 FROM employees AS t

Comment: @irhabymailed4u Add the query to your question and explain why it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Still, it is a tough assignment...

```
 SELECT x.date, MIN(y.date) y_date,DATEDIFF(MIN(y.date),x.date) days
FROM
(
SELECT hiredate date FROM employees
UNION 
SELECT terminationdate FROM employees
) x
JOIN
(
SELECT hiredate date FROM employees
UNION 
SELECT terminationdate FROM employees
UNION
SELECT CURDATE())
y
ON y.date > x.date
GROUP BY x.date
ORDER BY days DESC LIMIT 1;
```