# Advanced MySQL Query select and compare time in one field

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Employees
  EmpID : int(10)
  Firstname: varchar(100)
  Lastname: varchar(100)
  HireDate: timestamp
  TerminationDate: timestamp

  AnnualReviews
  EmpID: int(10)
  ReviewDate: timestamp
```

What is query that returns each employee and for each row/employee include the greatest number of employees that worked for the company at any time during their tenure and the first date that maximum was reached.
So far, this is my query:

```
select *, (select count(empid) from employees where terminationdate between t.hiredate and t.terminationdate)
 from employees as t
 group by empid
```

Comment: you were just helped here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866256/advanced-mysql-query then you disappeared without accepting any answer. now you are asking what is probably question #2 of your homework. read the FAQ of this site and start showing some good manners.

Comment: ok I have solved it by myself

Comment: I don't care. you still should reward people helping you for free and accept useful/working answers. this is what StackOverflow is about

Answer (score 1):

What you have is close.

But there's more work to do.

We'd to work out the conditions that determine how many employees were "working" at any point in time (i.e. at a given timestamp value.) The condition I'd check:

```
HireDate <= timestamp < TerminationDate
```

We'd need to extend that comparison, so that a NULL value for `TerminationDate` would be handled like it were a point in time *after* the timestamp value. That's easy enough to do.)

```
HireDate <= timestamp AND ( timestamp < TerminationDate OR TerminationDate IS NULL
```

So, something like this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM Employees e
  WHERE ( :timestamp >= e.HireDate )
    AND ( :timestamp <  e.TerminationDate OR e.TerminationDate IS NULL)
```

That "count" value would remain the same, and would only change for a "hire" or "terminate" event.

If we got a distinct list of all timestamps for all "hire" and "terminate" events, we could get the number of employees at that point in time.

So, this query would give us the employee count every time the employee count might change:

```
 SELECT t.ts     AS `as_of`
      , COUNT(1) AS `employee_count`
   FROM Employees e
   JOIN ( SELECT t.TerminationDate AS ts
            FROM Employees t
           WHERE t.TerminationDate IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY t.TerminationDate
           UNION
          SELECT h.HireDate AS ts
            FROM Employees h
           WHERE h.HireDate IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY h.HireDate
        ) t
     ON ( t.ts >= e.HireDate )
    AND ( t.ts <  e.TerminationDate OR e.TerminationDate IS NULL)
  GROUP BY t.ts
```

We could use that result (as an inline view) and join that to particular Employee, and get just the rows that have an `as_of` timestamp that matches the period of employment for that employee. Then just pulling out the maximum `employee_count`. It wouldn't be difficult to identify the earlier of multiple `as_of` dates, if that maximum `employee_count` occurred multiple times.

(The wording of the question leaves open a question, the "earliest date" *ever* that the employee count met or exceeded the maximum that occurred during an employees tenure, or just the earliest date within the employees tenure that the maximum was reached. It's possible to get either result.)

That's just one way to approach the problem.